# Missing developer payload after SUBSCRIPTION_IN_GRACE_PERIOD event

Tags: in-app-billing, google-play-developer-api

Is it a correct behavior, that assigned developer payload during acknowledgment of a subscription purchase is empty when the subscription is entering in grace period?

After I've got SUBSCRIPTION_IN_GRACE_PERIOD event, I'm calling the [get](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get) method from Purchases.subscriptions resource and turning out, the developer payload is empty.

I thought that my assignment of the developer payload is failed, but before the subscription entered the grace period my subscription was a few times renewed (SUBSCRIPTION_RENEWED) and the developer payload existed that time.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/133782951

Comment: Ii've created a detailed issue on googles issue tracker as the above is marked fixed and perhaps mixes using the Android billing library to perform the acknowledgement and backend acknowledgement https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143870142